# Using activeStorage with i18n on expo not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, internationalization, expo

Trying to set an app using Typescript React on expo that can show a different language based on a user selection, but doesn't seem to be working.
I've made it store the selected language in `asyncStorage` and called `await AsyncStorage.getItem('language')` to get the language, my code is below. If console.log is run on asyncStorage, I was able to retrieve the value.

Interestingly, language works without any flaws when I use `Localization.locale`, so wondering if it's being `asyncStorage` is taking too long to get a result?

```
import I18n from 'i18n-js'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

import en from './en.json'
import zh from './zh.json'

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  zh
}

async function getLanguage() {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language')
    if (value != null) {
      I18n.locale = value.slice(0,2)
      I18n.fallbacks = true
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

getLanguage()

export function t(name: string) {
  return I18n.t(name)
}
```

Language selector (stores the selected language in asyncStorage)

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import { Updates } from 'expo';


export default function LanguageChange() {

const onPress = async (language: string) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('language', language);
    Updates.reload();
}


 return (
    <View style={styles.languageContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress("en")}>
              <Text>English</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress('zh-CN')}>
              <Text>Chinese</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Edit 1**

I've tried using `.then` as well to see if there was a different result, but it's still the same.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((result) => {
  I18n.locale = result.slice(0,2)
})
```

Comment: You might have to double check that `value` is actually what you intended it to be. Can you perhaps do an equality check (`===`) with a string that you know does work?

Comment: I've checked, the values returned from AsyncStorage and Localization.locale is the same

Comment: @JohnnyChan ever found a solution?